NGINX is not populating X-Forwarded-For
I do have setup the NGINX as:
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
set_real_ip_from 192.168.78.1;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;

But it is still not showing in my page:
Array
(
    [LANG] => en_US.UTF-8
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/snap/bin
    [NOTIFY_SOCKET] => /run/systemd/notify
    [USER] => www-data
    [INVOCATION_ID] => d082f70da69f4d498d189756c552884a
    [JOURNAL_STREAM] => 8:366249
    [SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID] => 75975
    [MEMORY_PRESSURE_WATCH] => /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/php8.3-fpm.service/memory.pressure
    [MEMORY_PRESSURE_WRITE] => c29tZSAyMDAwMDAgMjAwMDAwMAA=
    [HOME] => /var/www
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => patrikx3-language=en; _ga=GA1.1.43115710.1721373331; _ga_HTGWCJY45K=GS1.1.1721373330.1.0.1721373367.0.0.0
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => hu,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br, zstd
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST] => document
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER] => ?1
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE] => navigate
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE] => none
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_DNT] => 1
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM] => "Linux"
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE] => ?0
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA] => "Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_HOST] => patrikx3.com
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [SERVER_NAME] => patrikx3.com
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 192.168.78.20
    [REMOTE_USER] => 
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 59602
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 192.168.78.1
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.24.0
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [HTTPS] => on
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/patrikx3.com/public
    [DOCUMENT_URI] => /info.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /info.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /info.php
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => 
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/patrikx3.com/public/info.php
    [PATH_INFO] => 
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED] => 
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /info.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1721393361.3468
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1721393361
)

What could be the problem?

can you post your full nginx config?  feel free to redact hostnames (e.g. change from mysub.mydomain.tld to mysub.example.com).  Can you also indicate what test request you are making (GET, POST, etc) and what URI/query?  Looks like you are logging something from PHP which is NOT nginx.  Are you using php-fpm or something else?  What does your nginx php config look like?

From the docs: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html#:~:text=The%20ngx_http_realip_module%20module%20is%20used%20to%20change%20the%20client%20address%20and%20optional%20port%20to%20those%20sent%20in%20the%20specified%20header%20field.

The ngx_http_realip_module module is used to change the client address and optional port to those sent in the specified header field.

So, if the request does not have a value set for the X-Forwarded-For header when handled by your NGinx instance, there there is nothing to be replaced...  E.g. the request is directly from a browser/client and not via a proxy/loadbalancer/gateway
Alternatively, it could be that the proxy/loadbalancer is setting a different header with the IP that you want - e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/409155/x-real-ip-header-empty-with-nginx-behind-a-load-balancer
